# Laravel - How to make a multi-filter with array of objects?

Tags: php, laravel, loops, orm, back

So, I'm trying to make a method where I can receive an array of objects with the params that I need to do a search in my database.
Example:

```
[{ "field": "name", "operator": "=", "term": "john" },
 { "field": "id", "operator": "=", "term": "3" }]
```

I'm receiving it, what I'm trying to do now is:
A loop where I can make a search on my database on FIELD, where OPERATOR, TERM

I don't know if I exaplained it well, but I think it would be something like this:

```
myForLoop ...
Table::where(FIELD, OPERATOR, TERM)
```

Is it correct? How it would be a method like that? I'm kinda noob in laravel.

Thanks in advance you all!

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
$json='[{ "field": "name", "operator": "=", "term": "john" },
 { "field": "id", "operator": "=", "term": "3" }]';
$data=json_decode($json);

$result=ModelName::where(function ($query)use($data){

    if(isset($data)&&count($data)){
        foreach ($data as $value){
            $query->where($value->field,$value->operator,$value->term);
        }
    }

})->get();
```

or

```
$json='[{ "field": "name", "operator": "=", "term": "john" },{ "field": "id", "operator": "=", "term": "3" }]';
     
$data=json_decode($json);

$where=[];

if(isset($data)&&count($data)){
    foreach($data as $value){
        $where[]=[$value->field,$value->operator,$value->term];
    }
}
    
$result=ModelName::where(function ($query)use($where){
    
    $query->where($where);
    
})->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! The $json actually is the request that I send... but the thing is: it has to be where something, orWhere something else, like, in the example: Where name=john OR id=3.

Comment: I tried the solution tho, it returned me all the data from my db and I'm searching out why

Comment: try first one if you have orWhere case  foreach ($data as $value){
            $query->orWhere($value->field,$value->operator,$value->term);
        }

Comment: try dd($data) before if condition .may be its empty

Comment: $data=json_decode($request); $where=[]; dd($data);, yeah it's null...

Comment: first dd($request->all()); check what you get

Comment: thanks! actually is an array of arrays... shouldn't it be an array of objects?

Comment: make sure data should match what you provided in question or else my answer work.better update request all result in question